# Formstone Classic Selecter - jQuery Clone and Modify GUID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selecter-plugin

Is it possible when using jQuery Clone to increment the current GUID of an object?

At present, when the selecter is initialised all selects, including hidden ones, are assigned a GUID.

The cloning process simply duplicates the template div. The problem being that it also clones the GUID of the hidden select, which means any dynamically added selects are rendered unusable as more than one select share the same guid.

To implement all selects on a form I am using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").selecter();
});
```

The code to create a clone of a row, which includes a select is as follows:

```
$('.addButton').on('click', function () {
    var $template = $('#Template'),
        $clone = $template
            .clone(true, true)
            .removeClass('hide')
            .removeAttr('id')
            .attr('title', 'DynamicRow')
            .insertBefore($template);

    $("#Form").validate();

    $clone.find('[name="Type[]"]').rules("add", { required: true });     
});
```

I have also included the HTML below to demonstrate what is being cloned:

```
<div class="fieldset">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div class="field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
            <select name="Type[]" id="Type[]">
                <option value="">Type</option>
                <option value="1">Other</option>
                <option value="2">Maintenance</option>
                <option value="3">Attendance</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fieldset hide" id="Template">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div class="field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
            <select name="Type[]" id="Type[]">
                <option value="">Type</option>
                <option value="1">Other</option>
                <option value="2">Maintenance</option>
                <option value="3">Attendance</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Formstone Classic Selecter library can be found at:

https://github.com/FormstoneClassic/Selecter/blob/master/jquery.fs.selecter.js

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I could find, was to initialise each form select individually, therefore `$("select").selecter();` could not be used as this initialises all selects, including hidden ones.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fieldset" id="Types">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div class="field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
            <select name="Type[]" id="Type[]">
                <option value="">Type</option>
                <option value="1">Other</option>
                <option value="2">Maintenance</option>
                <option value="3">Attendance</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fieldset hide" id="Template">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div class="field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
            <select name="Type[]" id="Type[]">
                <option value="">Type</option>
                <option value="1">Other</option>
                <option value="2">Maintenance</option>
                <option value="3">Attendance</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To initialise the first select I used `$('#Types').find('[name="Type[]"]').selecter();` and to initialise the hidden clone select I used `$clone.find('[name="Type[]"]').selecter();`

I hope this proves useful to others.